# Xamarin.Forms 3.6 breaking carouselview?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Xamarin.Forms 3.6 has included the CarouselView, so I cant use the nuget package anymore, but shipped version seems to be lacking some features, more specifically indicators seems to be missing entirely?

Here is my old code, which does not compile anymore:

```
            // Create the carousel
            _carouselView = new CarouselView()
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            };

            _carouselView.ItemTemplate = template;
            _carouselView.SetBinding(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, nameof(_viewModel.CarouselItems));
            _carouselView.SetBinding(CarouselView.PositionProperty, nameof(_viewModel.Position));

            // Create page-indicator
            var indicator = new CarouselIndicators { ItemsSource = _viewModel.CarouselItems };
            indicator.Margin = new Thickness(20, 20, 20, 0);
            indicator.SetBinding(CarouselIndicators.PositionProperty, nameof(_viewModel.Position));
```

CarouselView.Position and CarouselIndicators are not there in 3.6 :( Do I need to implement indicators manually in 3.6?

Comment: Are you refering to [this package](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView) ?

Comment: You are mixing up Xamarin Forms' [CarouselView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView/2.3.0-pre2) with AlexRainMan's [CarouselView](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView), Also are you sure Xamarin Forms has added it? Because I am not aware of this!!

Comment: Which NuGet version you use to add CarouselView .Do you mean preview version can use CarouselView.Position and CarouselIndicators? @Tompi

Comment: Yes @JuniorJiang-MSFT, I am on the preview version. Perhaps it was the official version which was merged into XF in 3.6 and that my problems are preview versions only...

Comment: @FabriBertani : No, Im talking about this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView

Comment: @G.hakim: No Im not mixing them, but it seems XF has merged PARTS of carouselview into 3.6, but not a featurecomplete version... SO I guess i will postpone updating XF until it is completely merged: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/150588/conflicting-carouselviews

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Xamarin.Forms 3.6 includes an implementation of CarouselView, if you upgrade from using Xamarin.Forms<3.6 and Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView to Xamarin.Forms 3.6 it is going to break. Because

1. the Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView nuget package is deprecated and hasn't been updated for 2 years
2. by having Xamarin.Forms 3.6 and Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView in parallel you will have a naming conflict between the 2 CarouselView elements
3. the Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView implementation in Xamarin.Forms 3.6 doesn't contain a `Position` property

A lot of projects switched to a community implementation of CarouselViews :

- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/106176/carouselview-position-problem
- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/129883/i-am-unable-to-set-the-particular-page-in-carousel-view
- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/132858/carouselview-state-of-the-union
- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/141384/how-to-implement-a-simple-carouselview

Solution for you would be :

1. Remove Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView
2. Add https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/CardView ([CardsView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CardsView) nuget package)
3. Upgrade Xamarin.Forms to 3.6
4. Change

```cs
_carouselView.SetBinding(CarouselView.PositionProperty, nameof(_viewModel.Position));
```

to

```cs
_carouselView.SetBinding(CardsView.SelectedIndexProperty, nameof(_viewModel.Position));
```